# Adding values to DataGridViewComboBoxColumn with autocomplete

Tags: c#, datagridview

I am new to using datagridviews and wanted to know how to populate certain fields.

I have created a form and added a datagridview (named GridSellProducts) with Visual Studio designer and added 8 columns with the first named `Item`. 
I have also changed the column type for `Item` to `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` also in design view.

I have the following data (product names) that I want to populate the combobox with for each row that may be added:

```
// get products
productsURL = "https://eko-app.com/Products/list_products/sessionId:" + sessionID + ".json";

var products = Products.GetProducts(productsURL);

List<string> productNames = new List<string>(); <-----the data  to add to the combobox

foreach (var p in products)
{
     var x = p.Product;

     foreach (var pn in x)
     {
          productNames.Add(pn.name);                  
     }        
}
```

How do I add the above data to the column combobox `Item` that will let a user be able to type a product name and also have an autocomplete feature. I am using WinForms.

Comment: (Assuming that you are using Windows.Forms) Look up the documentation for the [ComboBox.AutoCompleteMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode.aspx) property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To populate your list with `Items` property in `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn` use this:

```
     public DataGridViewComboBoxColumn cbColumn; // outside method for further use of inserting into DataBase

     cbColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
     bColumn.DataSource = productNames;
```

[MSDN DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.DataSource Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcomboboxcolumn.datasource%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)